# Istio Virtual service - enforce specific api version

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I am having troubles creating an object within specific api group it gets switced from alpha to beta, why? networking.istio.io/v1beta1 vs networking.istio.io/v1alpha3

Note: I can control in the crd virtualservice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve it myself later that day, I had to disable one of the apigroups within the specific crd that is responsible for the given object.
In that case it was editing:
kubectl edit crd virtualservices.networking.istio.io
And then change:

```
  versions:
  - name: v1alpha3
    served: true
    storage: true
  - name: v1beta1
    served: true
    storage: false
```

to

```
  versions:
  - name: v1alpha3
    served: true
    storage: true
  - name: v1beta1
    served: false
    storage: false
```

Then on redeploy I had the correct apigroup which I wanted.